# How can i get the input value to display on the screen after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, algorithm, palindrome

I am making an application that checks if a word is a palindrome, if it is a palindrome, it will display the word on the screen after submitting the form and say (word + "is a palindrome!"). i cant even get it to console.log either dont know to how get it to recognise the value that has been input.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pallindrome Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pallindrome Checker</h1>
    <form id='form'>
     <input id = 'pal' type = 'text'/>

     <input id = 'submit' type = 'button' value='submit' />
    </form>

    
           <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
function pallindrome(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        
    let letters = [];

    let rword="";
    
    let word = document.getElementById("pal").value = "";
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){e
        letters.push(word[i]);
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        rword += letters.pop();
    }
    
    if(rword === word) {
        console.log(word + "is a pallindrome!")
        
    }
        else{
            console.log(word + "is not a pallindrome!")
        }
    
   
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", pallindrome, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can console log or you can show an alert

```
function pallindrome(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        
      let letters = [];

      let rword="";
      let word = document.getElementById("pal").value;
      
    
      for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){e
          letters.push(word[i]);
      }
    
      for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
          rword += letters.pop();
      }
    
      if(rword === word) {
         console.log(word + "is a pallindrome!");
        alert('pallindrome');
      }else{
          console.log(word + "is not a pallindrome!");
        alert('not');
      }
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", pallindrome, false);
```

https://codepen.io/mhfuad/pen/jOWRxWw

Answer (score 0):

modify this line to get the value of the input element:

```js
let word = document.getElementById("pal").value;
```

```js
function pallindrome(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        
    let letters = [];

    let rword="";
    
    let word = document.getElementById("pal").value;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){e
        letters.push(word[i]);
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        rword += letters.pop();
    }
    
    if(rword === word) {
        console.log(word + " is a pallindrome!")
        
    }
        else{
            console.log(word + " is not a pallindrome!")
        }
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", pallindrome, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

just concatenate when building the reverse word

```js
function pallindrome(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        
    let letters = [];

    let rword='';
    
    let word = document.getElementById("pal").value ;
   
    
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){e
        rword =rword + word[word.length-1-i];
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    if(rword === word) {
        console.log(word + " is a pallindrome!")
        
    }
        else{
            console.log(word + " is not a pallindrome!")
        }
    
   
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", pallindrome);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pallindrome Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pallindrome Checker</h1>
    <form id='form'>
     <input id = 'pal' type = 'text'/>

     <input id = 'submit' type = 'button' value='submit' />
    </form>

    
           <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```